# Contact form with validation and response in php

Tags: php, forms, validation, response, contacts

I'm currently trying to write a contact form in html and php, but the send button does not respond and the message is also not sent to the email i also tried a different mail address but it didnt work either. I have not found the problem yet.

Html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
            <h3>Kontaktformular</h3>
            <form class="row" role="form" name="contact-form" id="contact-form" action="contact-send.php" method="POST">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="name" class="form-control contact-form " id="contact-name" placeholder="Name" name="contact[name]">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="contact-form form-control " type="text" placeholder="Email" name="contact[email]" id="contact-email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="contact-form form-control " type="text" placeholder="Betreff" name="contact[subject]" id="contact-subject">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group message">
                        <textarea class="form-control input-row-3 contact-form " rows="6" placeholder="Nachricht" name="contact[message]" id="contact-message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group text-right button-submit btn-submit">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark button-send">SENDEN</button>
                        <div class="message-success alert-success alert hidden"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php


$email = "trissa1992@gmail.com";


$required = array('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message');
$response = array('status' => 'failed', 'errors'=>array());

if(isset($_POST['contact'])) {
foreach($_POST['contact'] as $field => $value) {
    //check required field if empty
    if($value == '' && in_array($field, $required)) {
        $response['errors'][$field] = $field;
    }
}

//validate email
if(!isset($response['errors']['email'])) {
    if(!filter_var($_POST['contact']['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $response['errors']['email'] = 'email';
    }
}
}

if(empty($response['errors'])) {
$response['status'] = 'success';

$data = $_POST['contact'];

$headers = "";

$message = $data['message'];
$message .= "\n\n";
$message .= " Name: " . $data['name'];
$message .= " Email: " . $data['email'];

$subject = 'Subject: '. $data['subject']. "\r\n";
$headers = 'From: '. $data['email']. "\r\n" .'Reply-To: '. $data['email']. "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

} else {
    $response['status'] = 'failed';
}
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting and start doing some debugging, there are multiple things you need to check, some of them depending on what OS you are using and so on, but start with turning on error reporting and solve the errors coming up.

Comment: This form is working fine, with no errors, are you using localhost or live server?

Comment: im using a live server

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your mail functionality is not enabled, to enable it:

1. If Sendmail isn't installed, install it: apt-get install Sendmail
2. Configure hosts file correctly: nano /etc/hosts And make sure the line looks like this: 127.0.0.1 localhost yourhostnamehere
3. Run the sendmail config and answer 'Y' to everything: sendmailconfig
4. Restarted apache: service apache2 restart

Another Option is:

1. sudo apt-get install php-pear
2. sudo pear install mail
3. sudo pear install Net_SMTP
4. sudo pear install Auth_SASL
5. sudo pear install mail_mime
6. sudo apt-get install postfix
7. you should get an install dialog: make sure Internet site is selected and the Mail server name is localhost
8. sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini set 
   sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
9. service apache2 restart

Now you're all done!

Comment: i have a provider for my website how does that work?

Comment: if you have access to the server then try to send mail from using simple php code, or contact your admin